# window.navigator.userLanguage not found in IDE

Tags: angular, translation, visual-studio-code, language-detection

I'm working on an Angular 2 App with Visual Studio Code (Typescript) and I want to read the User Language for translation.

"navigate.language" works (at least for Chrome,...)

but I can't code navigate.userLanguage for IE - my IDE tells me that this .userLanguage doesn't exist.

Do I have to import or define something?

Code in the AppComponent.ts:

```
public translatedText: string;
public supportedLanguages: any[];
public userLang = navigator.language;  // this one works fine
```

// but it should be: 
   //public userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

```
constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // standing data
    this.supportedLanguages = [
    { display: 'English', value: 'en' },
    { display: 'Español', value: 'es' },
    { display: '华语', value: 'zh' },
    { display: 'Deutsch', value: 'de' },
    ];

    this.subscribeToLangChanged(); // subscribe to language changes

    // set language
    this._translate.setDefaultLang('en'); // set English as default
    this._translate.enableFallback(true); // enable fallback

    // set current language
    this.selectLang(this.userLang);
}

isCurrentLang(lang: string) {
    // check if the selected lang is current lang
    return lang === this._translate.currentLang;
}

selectLang(lang: string) {
    // set current lang;
    this._translate.use(lang);
}

refreshText() {
    // refresh translation when language change
    this.translatedText = this._translate.instant('hello world');
}

subscribeToLangChanged() {
// refresh text
// please unsubribe during destroy
return this._translate.onLangChanged.subscribe(x => this.refreshText());
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._translate.onLangChanged.unsubscribe();
}
```

}

Hope for help ;o) 
Best, Nik

Comment: Did you test the code? The intllisense does not really work for all javascript properties. The property works fine in IE console.

Comment: Thanks! You are right - it looked as it won't work because what comes back is "de-CH" and not only "de" which I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Did you test the code? The intellisense does not really work for all javascript properties. The property works fine in IE console.

Posted as answer, in case someone stumbles on this from google and doesn't notice the comments.